# passing javascript value into php methods

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, encoding

```
var PId   = 12;
var catId = 3;
var Param = 'productid='+PId+'&CatId='+catId;
var encriptedCode = '<?php echo $this->encrypt->encode( .... need to pass the Param .... );?>';
```

I am trying to pass the javascript value into php method, whatever i am trying it's not working. Any one help me to detect where i am wrong. using this code in time of ajax call

Comment: this needs to be done with ajax

Comment: need to return the whole thing from ajax and pass only the js as param??

Comment: Btw, can you make this encode with javascript or it's secret?

Comment: i am using Codeigniter and need to follow the encription method so i can decrept from another view

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
encriptedCode = '<?php echo $this->encrypt->encode(?>Param<?php);?>';
```

Comment: that is detecting 'Param' as string

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make an Ajax request and pass that information through using the GET request.

Something like this:

```js
var PId   = 12;
var catId = 3;
var Param = 'productid='+PId+'&CatId='+catId;
$.get( Param ); // makes the call to the PHP script
```

Then in your PHP file you can retrieve the data passed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need result of $this->encrypt->encode method to use in your JS file. So you need to retrieve it using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest).

```
var PId   = 12;
var catId = 3;
var Param = 'productid='+PId+'&CatId='+catId;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var encriptedCode;

req.open('GET', 'path/to/your/file.php?' + Param, true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if(req.status == 200) {
            encriptedCode = req.responseText;
            // Do some something with your encrypted code
        } else {
            // Handle error here
        }

    }
};
req.send(null);
```

and the PHP file should looks like here

```
<?php
   // Load here libs for encryption
   $productId = (int)$_GET['productid'];
   $catId = (int)$_GET['CatId'];
   echo $encryptObj->encrypt->encode($productId, $catId);
```